# Implementing a timeout on a multiprocessing process in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeout, python-multiprocessing

I do:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
q = mp.Queue()
p = mp.Process(target=lambda x: x, args=('foo',))
p.start()
p.join(10)
if p.exitcode == 0:
   q.get()
else:
   print("We timed out.")
```

What I expect is that my tiny `x->x` function will block for at most 10 seconds. If it finished before then, I get the result sooner than that. If it takes longer than that (obviously not in this toy example, but in other cases), then the process terminates after 10 seconds and I am able to check `exitcode` to determine that we have indeed timed out.

But when I execute this code, what happens instead is that `q.get()` runs forever. Why does this occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q.get()` runs forever since it blocks by default, and you never put anything into the queue.

You can use `q.get(block=False)` or `q.get_nowait()` (which is equivalent to the former). But remember that it will raise `queue.Empty`, so you should handle that.